# Difference in size between parser and slurper?

Tags: groovy, xml-parsing

I am trying to use groovy for xml processing and still finding it difficult to understand its behavior. Can someone explain to me why the following program spits out 1 and 0 please? I am expecting 0 in both cases as the 'onenode' element has no children...what am I missing here?

```
def text = """
 <characters>
   <props>
      <prop>dd</prop>
   </props>
   <character id="1" name="Wallace">
       <likes>cheese</likes>
   </character>
   <character id="2" name="Gromit">
       <likes>sleep</likes>
   </character>
   <onenode>help</onenode>
</characters>
"""

def xmlp = new XmlParser().parseText(text)
println xmlp.onenode[0].children().size() // prints out 1

def xmls = new XmlSlurper().parseText(text)
println xmls.onenode[0].children().size() // prints out 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference is the way the parsed tree is built (both in the classes used, and how the methods work).

If we write a closure to interrogate the tree:

```
def dumpTypeTree = { node, prefix = '' ->
  def name  = node.respondsTo( 'name' ) ? "${node.name()} -- " : ''
  def clazz = node.getClass().name
  def txt   = node.respondsTo('text') ? node.text() : node
  println "${prefix}${name}${clazz} '${txt}'"
  if( node.respondsTo( 'children' ) ) {
    node.children().each { child ->
      owner.call( child, "$prefix  " )
    }
  }
}
```

When we call this method with the `XmlParser` constructed tree:

```
dumpTypeTree( new XmlParser().parseText(text) )
```

we get:

```
characters -- groovy.util.Node ''
  props -- groovy.util.Node ''
    prop -- groovy.util.Node 'dd'
      java.lang.String 'dd'
  character -- groovy.util.Node ''
    likes -- groovy.util.Node 'cheese'
      java.lang.String 'cheese'
  character -- groovy.util.Node ''
    likes -- groovy.util.Node 'sleep'
      java.lang.String 'sleep'
  onenode -- groovy.util.Node 'help'
    java.lang.String 'help'
```

As you can see, the `onenode` node contains a `String` which is the text contents of that Node.  And the `text()` call returns what we would expect.

However, calling it with XmlSlurper:

```
dumpTypeTree( new XmlSlurper().parseText(text) )
```

gives us:

```
characters -- groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild 'ddcheesesleephelp'
  props -- groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild 'dd'
    prop -- groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild 'dd'
  character -- groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild 'cheese'
    likes -- groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild 'cheese'
  character -- groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild 'sleep'
    likes -- groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild 'sleep'
  onenode -- groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild 'help'
```

As you can see, there are no `String` children, and only calling `text()` on leaf nodes would make any sense, as outside the leaves, we get all of the text concatenated together.

Anyway, hope this explains the difference in number of children

Comment: Thanks Tim. That explains a lot to me.